# Android Studio 1.0 - Using stock camera app and customizing file name after picture

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Ok, so this code works great to call the stock android camera app:

```
public void clickEvent(View e) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

However, I need to capture that picture file after it's taken, rename it and maybe place it somewhere else.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What research have you done / things have you tried so far?

Comment: "this code works great to call the stock android camera app" -- note that this does not use "the stock android camera app". It uses whatever camera app the user chooses. There are hundreds, if not thousands, of possible apps that will respond, including dozens of different ones that come pre-installed on devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the EXTRA_OUTPUT extra on the intent to tell whatever app responds to the intent where to put the file.